# grep or sed for word containing string

Tags: regex, sed, grep

example file:

```
blahblah 123.a.site.com   some-junk
yoyoyoyo 456.a.site.com   more-junk
hihohiho 123.a.site.org   junk-in-the-trunk
lalalala 456.a.site.org   monkey-junk
```

I want to grep out all those domains in the middle of each line, they all have a common part `a.site` with which I can grep for, but I can't work out how to do it without returning the whole line?

Maybe sed or a regex is need here as a simple grep isn't enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*a\.site[^ ]*' input
```

or

```
awk '{print $2}' input
```

or

```
sed -e 's/.*\([^ ]*a\.site[^ ]*\).*/\1/g' input
```

Comment: Thank you,  the top one is exactly what I needed. This has given me some material to Google for also, so double thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this to find anything in that position

```
  $ sed -r "s/.* ([0-9]*)\.(.*)\.(.*)/\2/g"

 [0-9]* - For match number zero or more time.
 .*     - Match anything zero or more time.
 \.     - Match the exact dot.
 ()     - Which contain the value particular expression in parenthesis, it can be printed using \1,\2..\9. It contain only 1 to 9 buffer space. \0 means it contain all the expressed pattern in the expression.
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained your answer a bit, its a little complex for reg newbs like me :)